# Laravel 5.3 Mail not sending to queue job after submit data

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.3

i had been trying to solve the queue mail for few days, but still i can't find the solution for that.
Please look at my controller, job, mail

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contact;
use App\Jobs\SendEmail;

class MailController extends Controller
{
public function getContact(){
    return view ('mail');
}

public function postContact(Request $request){

        $contact = new Contact;
        $contact->email = $request['email'];
        $contact->name = $request['name'];
        $contact->subject = $request['subject'];
        $contact->save(); 

        dispatch(new SendEmail($contact));
        return back();
}
}
```

job

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
Use App\Mail\EmailContact;

class SendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $contact;

public function __construct(Contact $contact)
{
    $this->contact = $contact;
}

public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $email = new EmailContact($this->contact);
    $mailer->to($this->contact->email)->send($email);
}
}
```

Mail

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;
use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EmailContact extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $contact;
public function __construct(Contact $contact)
{
    $this->contact = $contact;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.contact')->with([
        'email' => $this->contact->email,
        'name' => $this->contact->name,
        'subject' => $this->contact->subject,
    ]);
}
}
```

After that i add php artisan queue:work
But the result is still the same as using SEND.
is there any wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `ShouldQueue` in your mailable class.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class EmailContact extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
```

Also verify your queue driver. By default laravel sets the queue driver to `sync`. Which means any queue jobs will run like normal code even if you are trying to queue it. You need to implement a queue first for it to work. Try database or redis queues.

`QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`

Comment: hi thanks, i had finally solve that issue. in my .env file, my QUEUE_DRIVER=database. 1st i check dd(config('queue.default')); it's output is still sync. so i clear the cache by php artisan config:clear and finally it works! should i really need to implement ShouldQueue in my mailable class. Because without implement it, it still can work

Comment: Ye i've noticed that you've implemented `ShouldQueue` in your job class. So it should work as you dispatch the job and not the mail directly. But you can even call the mailable directly from your controller, in those scenarios you may need to implement it.